# SVG from blender issue

Tags: svg, blender

i'm having issues with SVG Freestyle Export from blender. 3D Scene in blender

Fills issues

I have a problem regarding strokes that do not stop when they intersect with the face of another object. I can address this issue by using booleans, but it forces me to flatten all my geometry nodes.

Previsualisation in blender

This is more serious concerning filling shapes; it doesn't seem to consider depth and renders the filling shapes randomly." Have you ever experienced something similar ? Thanks for your help ! I'm out of idea.

Comment: You should ask blender stackexhange

Comment: Sorry to say, but this one's pretty far outside the skills and experience of graphic designers as a group - *really* belongs on the blender Stack exchange site.